# Type 'string' does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible

Tags: ios, swift

In my code in Swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let stringIdent = String(format: "section_1_%d", section)
    return NSLocalizedString(stringIdent, comment: nil)
}
```

I am shown an error when running the build:

> Type 'string' does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible

This code always worked in Objective-C.

What could be wrong in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`comment` is declared as `String` and not `String?`. You cannot use `nil` there. Use `""` instead.

```
 return NSLocalizedString(stringIdent, comment: "")
```